# How do I solve a quadratic bezier curve for x and y individually?

Tags: quadratics, bezier-curve

I'm looking at specific cases of quadratic bezier curves defined by three points: p1 = [0,0],
p2 = [i,m],
p3 = [d,m], where *i*,*d*, and *m* are positive real numbers and *i* < *d*. p1 and p3 are the start and end points, p2 is the control point, which does not fall on the curve.

How can I derive the equations to solve for x and y individually? I understand that not all bezier curves are aligned to the x and y axis, so might not follow the usual pattern of a quadratic equation or formula, but intuitively it should be possible to state y = f(x) and x = f(y) because we're only concerned with one root and we know which direction it grows.

Comment: What are these 3 points? Are they the control points? Are they points that lie on the curve?

Comment: p1 and p3 are the start and end points, p2 is the control point, which does not lie on the curve. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear Bézier between two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ is given by the linear transition $$b_{1,2}(t) = (1-t)P_1 + tP_2\tag 1$$ from $P_1$ to $P_2$ as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$.
For a quadratic Bézier, we take two linear ones and interpolate them just like $(1)$:

$$\begin{align}
b_{1,2,3}(t) &= (1-t)b_{1,2}(t) + tb_{2,3}(t) \\
&= (1-t)((1-t)P_1+tP_2) + t((1-t)P_2 + tP_3) \\
&= (1-t)^2P_1+2t(1-t)P_2 + t^2 P_3 \tag 2\\
%&= P_1 - 2tP_1 + t^2P_1 + 2tP_2 - 2t^2P_2 + t^2P_3 \\
%&= t^2 (P_1-2P_2+P_3) + 2t(P_2-P_1)  + P_1  \tag 3\\
\end{align}$$

In terms of $x$ and $y$-coordinates $(2)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\binom xy &= (1-t)^2\binom{x_1}{y_1} + 2t(1-t)\binom{x_2}{y_2}+ t^2\binom{x_3}{y_3} \\
&=  2t(1-t)\binom{i}{m}+ t^2\binom{d}{m} \tag 3\\
\end{align}$$

The final step is left for you: In order to get a function in terms of $x$, i.e. $y(x)$, express $t$ as a function of $x$.  This is just solving a quadratic in $t$.  Then plug in the resulting $t(x)$ into the $y$-coordinate.  The quadratic equation for $x$ is:

$$x = t^2(d-2i)+2ti \tag 4$$

Solve $(4)$ for $t$ and then plug $t$ back into $(3)$.  As $x$ ranges from $0$ to $d$, $t$ will range from $0$ to $1$.

---

As some comment asked for which branch of the square-root to take: Solving $(4)$, which is the $x$-component of $(3)$, for $t$ yields:

$$t = \frac{-i\pm\sqrt{i^2+(d-2i)x}}{d-2i}\tag 5$$
We take the "$+$" branch because it maps $x=0\mapsto t=0$ and $x=d\mapsto t=1$ due to $d>i>0$.  The $y$-component of $(3)$ is
$$y = mt(2-t)\tag 6$$

---

In the special case of $d=2i$, equation $(4)$ decays to a linear equation and $t=x/(2i)$. In order to avoid handling different cases, extend $(5)$ with $\sqrt{\cdots}+i$ and rewrite as

$$\begin{align}
t &= \frac{\sqrt{i^2+(d-2i)x}-i}{d-2i} \\
&= \frac{i^2+(d-2i)x-i^2}{(d-2i)(\sqrt{i^2+(d-2i)x}+i)} \\
&= \frac{x}{\sqrt{i^2+(d-2i)x}+i} \tag 7\\
\end{align}$$
so that $d=2i$ is no more problem.  Notice that the denominator of $(7)$ is always positive.

Here is a [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kevrqje9rw) showing the formulae and values.  Notice that the sliders are such that $d =2i=6$.

Comment: Is (4) just a rearrangement of (3) with only the x component? Also, why must d and i be known to proceed with (4)? Is it that we can't know in advance which root t we want until after these values are plugged in? Also, does it follow that y = t^2(-m)+2tm for (4)?

Comment: @Lake: $(4)$ is the $x$-component of $(3)$ rearranged in powers of $t$.

Comment: @Lake: According to the question, $i$, $d$ and $m$ are the known values. We know the range of $x$ and also the range of $t$, this should be enough to sort out the correct root. According to $(3)$, $y=m(2t-t^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for all this. I think I understand better. What happens in the case of i being exactly half of d? Won't that result in a divide by zero?

Comment: @Lake: If $d-2i = 0$ then $(4)$ decays to linear and $t=x/(2i)$. If you want, you can recover this also from $(5)$ by taking the limit $d\to2i$, but that complication is not needed.

Comment: I see. I'm implementing this solution in code, so I need to handle the linear case separately. It's working swimmingly though, and I don't see any other special cases I need to handle. I tried to upvote your answer, but it looks like I'm 2 away from the 15 karma I need to do so. Regardless, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Lake: I rewrote the equation for $t$ in equation $(7)$ so that no special case is needed any more.  Special cases can be annoying when using floating-point arith, and you want to avoid checking two numbers for equality due to omnipresent rounding and representation errors..

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 points do define the quadratic relation: $$y=\frac{m\cdot x\cdot (d+i-x)}{d\cdot i}$$
but they *don't* define a quadratic bezier curve, because you haven't specified which parameter value $0<t_2<1$ that has to correspond to $p_2$. A particular choice of $t_2$ could easily give you a parabola that is rotated in a way so that neither $y = f(x)$ nor $x = f(y)$ would hold for all $x,y$.

Comment: I was under the impression that t2 could be deduced for any 3 control points - or is there more than one quadratic bezier curve that uses any 3 control points?

Comment: @Lake There is one for each value of $t_2$ in the interval $(0,1)$

Comment: The middle “control point” of a quadratic Bézier curve does not lie on the curve (in general), it’s the intersection of the end tangents. So, no value of $t_2$ is needed. The three control points uniquely define the curve.

Comment: If we were looking for a curve passing **through** three given points, then your reasoning would be valid. But we’re not. Perhaps the OP clarified this after you wrote your answer.